# Why doesn't my .indexOf read the position of the characters in my string

Tags: javascript, string

I am currently trying to get my .indexOf to read the position of my characters in my string.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var myString = 'I\'m a "fun ninja" string';

   if (myString.indexOf("ninja") === -1)
    {
        
        console.log ("The word ninja starts at position " + myString.indexOf("ninja"));

    } else {
        
        console.log ("The word ninja is not in the string");
        
    }
```

It's supposed to say, "The word ninja starts at position 11" but what it ends up saying is "The word ninja is not in the string", when it obviously is in the string. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted and it looks like the string has issues. You are having a single quote inside a string enclosed by single quotes. A fiddle would help

Comment: What would be proper formatting? Any suggestions?

Comment: Refer to my answer. About the escaping of quotes and also code block in the question was previously not highlighted, which I see you have updated. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you the desired result. 2 things to note:

1. The string is  built using single quotes, so any single quote inside that needs to be escaped with a backslash `\`
2. The comparison in the `if` statement is wrong. You should check if the index is not -1, which means the string is actually there.

   ```
   var myString = 'I\'m a "fun ninja" string';

   if (myString.indexOf("ninja") !== -1) {

      console.log ("The word ninja starts at position " + myString.indexOf("ninja"));

   } else {

      console.log ("The word ninja is not in the string");

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: @LyndaMClark Glad I could help.

Comment: @LyndaMClark If this helped you and you see fit, please mark this as the answer so it could help others too!

Answer (score 4):

the problem is in your if statement, you are comparing if the result of indexOf is === -1, but if the indexOf function returns -1 it means that the substring isn't found, as he finds "ninja" in your string it doesnt execute the code and jumps to the else instead.

It should be:

```
if (myString.indexOf("ninja") != -1){
    console.log ("The word ninja starts at position " + myString.indexOf("ninja"));
} else {
    console.log ("The word ninja is not in the string");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I'm learning from a gentleman from Youtube the === must be outdated.

Comment: @LyndaMClark `===` is not outdated. It compares type along with the value. Whereas `==` will only compare value and not care about the type.

Comment: @LyndaMClark `===` still works fine and checks if `a` is [strictly equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality#Description) to `b`. However if the returned index is `-1` it means there is no match found, so why are you trying to log that there is? The return value is clearly documented "The index of the first occurrence of *`searchValue`*, or `-1` if not found." - [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Return_value)

Comment: Thanks Shahzad, I'm still trying to understand === & == and the rest.

Comment: Thank you 3limin4t0r. Great explanation and great point made.